# Excel VBA - Sheet Property does not assign a field as it should

Tags: vba, excel

new to VBA--Trying to use Sheet properties like I would use Getters and Setters in OOP languages. I have the following code in Sheet1(simplified for clarity):

```
Option Explicit

Private bAllowChange As Boolean

Public Property Let AllowChange(bLetAllowChange As Boolean)
    bAllowChange = bLetAllowChange
End Property
```

I would expect that when the `AllowChange` property is called by a sub in another module, the `bAllowChange` field will be updated accordingly. By using the debugging feature of VBE I can see that `AllowChange` is being passed the correct value (`bLetAllowChange` takes on the correct value) but the line

```
bAllowChange = bLetAllowChange
```

does not assign the value to `bAllowChange`. If I set `bAllowChange` to Public then it works as expected, however this defeats the purpose of using Properties in the first place. This is probably something simple that I'm not understanding about scope in VBA. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you really want to use get/let then you want is to set up a class.  See this link, for example, http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx

Comment: Isn't Sheet a class in VBA? If so, shouldn't Properties work for them? If not, would I need to  use normal Subs/Functions? I am using these properties to support a Worksheet_Change subroutine, that's why I am working in the Sheet and not a separate module.

Comment: I believe the issue is that you expect the properties to be persistent.  They are not.  As soon as you break the code or close the workbook the properties reset.  You can add custom properties to the workbook [Workbook.CustomDocumentProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-customdocumentproperties-property-excel) but not to an indivual worksheet.

Comment: By breaking I mean clicking the stop button in the VBE editor.  Doing so will reset all the class level variables

Comment: I worded it poorly.

Comment: @ThomasInzina Either that or I read it poorly :D  (It's **usually** the latter, so I wouldn't be surprised if I was the only person who read it that way :D)

Comment: there is something else at play in your computer. i tried the code snippet that you posted, and `bAllowChange = bLetAllowChange` does update the `bAllowChange`    .... i am using excel2016 in win7

Comment: @ScottYoshida "I have the following code in Sheet1(simplified for clarity)" - How simplified is simplified?  Have you cut your code down so much that the problem does not exist in the code you posted?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I have marked @YowE3K 's response as the answer since, as I described the problem in the original question, his shows that it is valid code. My issue is therefore caused by something else which I will have to investigate and create a separate question.

Comment: I discovered the issue. The code did work, however I had a sub which ran immediately after was breaking execution and resetting the value, as @ThomasInzina suggested. This, combined with the fact that I was using the Watch feature incorrectly as YowE3K suggested, means I didn't notice this happening. Removing that sub allows the code to run as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

In Module1:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SetItToFalse()
    Sheet1.AllowChange = False
End Sub
Sub SetItToTrue()
    Sheet1.AllowChange = True
End Sub
```

In the sheet with a code name of `Sheet1`:

```
Option Explicit

Private bAllowChange As Boolean

Public Property Let AllowChange(bLetAllowChange As Boolean)
    bAllowChange = bLetAllowChange
End Property
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox bAllowChange
End Sub
```

With that code set up, I can invoke the `SetItToFalse` subroutine and then every selection change shows me it is `False`.  After invoking `SetItToTrue` every selection change shows me it is `True`.

Comment: I copied your code to a new Workbook and it behaves as you describe. However, I was initially confused as the Watch I had added to monitor `bAllowChange` showed it as `False` the entire time, despite subsequent Selection Changes showing the value to be `True`.

Furthermore, I tried to see if it was simply the Watch window lying to me in my original code, however the problem persists. There must be something else wrong with my code/computer/settings, so I will mark this question as answered since, as I described the problem, yours shows a solution.

Comment: @ScottYoshida When adding it to the Watch Window, did you ensure that it was `bAllowChange` in Sheet1 that you were watching?  You didn't accidentally try to watch `bAllowChange` in some other scope (e.g. `Module1` or some other sheet) did you?

Comment: I had selected (All Procedures) and (All Modules). This should allow me to watch it throughout any scope, right?

Comment: @ScottYoshida I think that will be the issue.  I suspect that can only be done for Public variables, not for Private ones.  Just add it for (All Procedures) and (Sheet1) and it will be visible for you (but only while you are on the code module for Sheet1 - it won't be visible when you leave that module due to it being Private)

Answer (score 3):

if you want persistent properties, try this (just an example of how to set/get/update/delete custom properties)

```
Sub customProperties()

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").customProperties.Add "abc123", 123
    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").customProperties(1)     ' custom properties are not indexed by name

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").customProperties(1).Value = "this is my data"
    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").customProperties(1)

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").customProperties(1).Delete


    ' CustomDocumentProperties Types
    ' msoPropertyTypeBoolean  2
    ' msoPropertyTypeDate     3
    ' msoPropertyTypeFloat    5
    ' msoPropertyTypeNumber   1
    ' msoPropertyTypeString   4


    ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Add Name:="xyz", LinkToContent:=False, Type:=msoPropertyTypeString, Value:="xyz"
    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("xyz")

    ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("xyz").Value = "abcdefg"
    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("xyz")

    ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("xyz").Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: I did not know that you could add a custom property to a worksheet.. +1 Kudos

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Worksheet's Names collection to store your custom Worksheets property values  permanently.

The main caveat to this is that the value is returned prefixed by an equal sign.  (e.g. after setting `name.Value = True` , name.Value would = `=True`).  I made a workaround for this in my example.

[image]

---

```
Public Property Let AllowChange(bLetAllowChange As Boolean)
    Dim n As Name
    On Error Resume Next
    Set n = Me.Names("bLetAllowChange")
    If n Is Nothing Then
        Set n = Me.Names.Add("bLetAllowChange", bLetAllowChange)
    End If
    n.Value = bLetAllowChange
    On Error GoTo 0
End Property

Public Property Get AllowChange() As Boolean
    Dim result As String
    On Error Resume Next
    result = Me.Names("bLetAllowChange").Value
    result = Right(result, Len(result) - 1)
    AllowChange = Application.Evaluate(result)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Property
```