# Why can I not change my project name?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change my Excel VBA project name but everytime I do this it always reverts back to the 'default' name of VBAProject.

So far I have tried renaming the project via the Properties Window and by Tools > VBA Project Properties - both times I saved the document but after closing and opening again, the name has defaulted back to VBAProject.

I have full access rights to this document and it is not ready only.  I have Trust Access to VBA Project enabled.

What else could prevent me from doing this?  I would have at least expected an error telling me I could not do this rather than lead me to believe this is possible!!

Comment: what problem are you trying to resolve by doing the name change?

Comment: I want to 'distinguish' between certain excel files by using something to identify it which isn't easily changed or accidentally modified.
I should add, that I have done this in the past before to other workbooks however not being a regular occurrence, I don't know when it stopped working!!

Comment: Are you saving the changes from the VBE save button, or from the Excel UI? The Excel UI is more reliable, especially if you also make a small change to the sheet/workbook. Does the workbook change survive the save, but not the project name change?

Comment: I have just tried this on my home PC (2016) and interestingly, it doesn't work the same as my work PC which is 2013.  As I am at home at the moment, I tried using both ways to save (VBE UI ad Excel UI) and they both worked and they both saved any changes to the code.
When I'm back in Monday i'll have to try saving via the Excel UI as this was one thing I didn't try; I only used the VBE save.

Comment: i posted an answer about using persistent custom properties here ... it shows you how to set a custom property in a workbook and also in each individual worksheet ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870595/excel-vba-sheet-property-does-not-assign-a-field-as-it-should/45871526#45871526

Comment: The only issue for us with custom properties is that they are exposed to the document management system which means they can accidentally/purposefully changed when others are changed which would then break the automation.
Granted, changing the project name is not full proof, but it has to be a deliberate action in order to change it; although not in my case :)

Comment: @cosmarchy I had that two several times and I couldn't figure out why it won't save. Apperently if you have the debug mode you cannot rename the project. If you cancle debug mode it works again. Was that the case?

Comment: @LucasRaphaelPianegonda unfortunately not.  I didn't have debug mode active when I tried to save.  Still at a loss really.  Although this is an ideal solution and I should be able to do it, I'm going to put it down to a Microsoft bug and move on.

Comment: "what problem are you trying to resolve by ...?" -- This type of response usually doesn't help and can be annoying. OP knows that he wants to make the change: either there's no way to do so or there is; if there is, does responder know how to  do so? If not, find out--cut to the chase; i.e., help somebody. If OP can't use response to effect what he needs to happen, then ask "why" he wants to do it since there may be an easier way or no way. Does this waste time and bandwidth? Maybe. It's just a suggestion. But automatically asking "Why" might be moreso.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the project name change to "stick" by clicking on Run - Design Mode before making the change.  I clicked on Run - Design Mode a second time, saved the file.  When I reopened, the name had still been changed.  This is in Excel 2016 VBA Editor.

Comment: @cosmarchy--You should consider marking this Answer as the accepted one.